# New Build, ASUS Board 1 long beep 2 short beep, no video

Tags: memory, motherboard

I am building a mid range computer for a friend, here are the specs:

- **Motherboard**: ASUS M5A97 LE R.20
- **Processor**: AMD FX 6300 6-core
- **Memory**: Crucial Ballistix 8GB DDR3-1866 (2x4GB)
- **Main Drive**: 250GB Samsung Evo 850 SSD
- **Graphics**: AMD Radeon HD 5450

I got everything installed and get one long and two short beeps, repeating. According to the web and the manual, the memory isn't detected. The processor is compatible with DDR3-1866, but the memory modules aren't listed in the "certified memory" list. According to Crucial's website, the memory should be compatible with the board.

---

**EDIT**: According AMD, the processor supports only DDR3-1866 memory, hence that particular speed.

**EDIT 2**: I also tried each memory module individually and in each of the 4 available slots. I also booted it with no modules and each time got the same One Long Two Short beeps on repeat.

---

Since I can't get past the POST, I can't provide more diagnostic information. I've tried one stick, no sticks, and both sticks in all the slots and get the same POST code.

Unfortunately I do not have another machine to test the memory in.

I am thinking either the memory is faulty or the motherboard itself is faulty. Are there any other diagnostics I can run? Am I better off returning the memory, the motherboard, or both and trying again?

Comment: Since there are two memory modules, I would recommend you to install the memory modules individually once and see what happens. I also have a M5A97 R2.0 which is a slightly updated version of the motherboard that you are using. Couple of years a go I got the same kind of beep code suddenly and I discovered one of my 4GB memory out of the two has failed suddenly. As far as I am concerned the RAM in question is compatible with the board. A faulty RAM is a possibility but a new board being faulty is less unlikely. Try to test the RAMs on another system if possible, just to be sure.

Comment: Hi thanks for you suggestion. I should have put in my original post that I tried each one individually and in all of the four slots available, and with no modules as well. Each boot resulted in the same One long Two short POST beeps. This is what is leading me to think I have faulty memory and/or motherboard on my hands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up being faulty memory. Exchanged it and put them in, no problems.